# Apache Tomcat home page not coming

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I installed Apache server (Tomcat 7.63) on client machine (Window 7 system 32 bit), The Java version used in client machine is (JDK 1.8 update 60)

**Problem**

Tomcat server is started by running the file (...\bin\Tomcat7.exe). But when I tried to open the home page (http://localhost:8080/) it is not coming on browser and I can see the following exception on Apache log:

```
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler process
SEVERE: Error reading request, ignored
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.AbstractCharsetProvider.lookup(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.AbstractCharsetProvider.access$000(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.AbstractCharsetProvider$1.next(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.AbstractCharsetProvider$1.next(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.charset.Charset.put(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.charset.Charset.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.charset.Charset$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.charset.Charset$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.nio.charset.Charset.availableCharsets(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.B2CConverter.<clinit>(B2CConverter.java:51
)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.<clinit>(ByteChunk.java:102)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes.<init>(MessageBytes.java:58)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes.<init>(MessageBytes.java:36)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes$MessageBytesFactory.newInstan
ce(MessageBytes.java:685)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes.newInstance(MessageBytes.java
:78)
at org.apache.coyote.Request.<init>(Request.java:83)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.<init>(AbstractProcessor.java:61)

at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.<init>(AbstractHttp1
1Processor.java:273)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.<init>(Http11Processor.java:
56)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.creat
eProcessor(Http11Protocol.java:165)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.creat
eProcessor(Http11Protocol.java:103)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:586)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoin
t.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskTh
read.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.nio.cs.CharsetMapping.load(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.CharsetMapping$1.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.CharsetMapping$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.nio.cs.CharsetMapping.get(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.ext.SJIS_0213$1.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.ext.SJIS_0213$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.nio.cs.ext.SJIS_0213.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
... 30 more

Exception in thread "http-bio-8085-exec-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:731)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoin
t.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskTh
read.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What is really weird to me that if I start Apache server from Services Management Console from the administrator account: Administrative Tools -> Services , it is working fine and I can see that the home page (http://localhost:8080/) is coming on browser.

**Question**

Why Apache home page is not coming if we run Apache server using the .exe file (...\bin\Tomcat7.exe) ? Why the home page is coming if the server started using Windows service ? In both cases the same .exe file is execute to run the server, what is the difference between the two cases ?

Comment: Check the service configuration, you're not supplying the same parameters.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch How can I compere the parameters in the two cases. In service case I right click on Tomcat service and I can see there is no parameter passed in (start parameters) bar. Can you tell me where I can find the parameters in both cases ?

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat cannot be started by using the `exe` directly (unless the correct parameters are supplied), you should use one of the included `.bat` files if you want to do that: `startup.bat`

Just be sure to define your environment variables, such as `JAVA_HOME`, and/or `JRE_HOME`

Comment: I did try to run Tomcat server using (...\bin\startup.bat) but the same exception thrown. I also double checked `JAVA_HOME` and it is pointing to the correct location.